# Chromium has no audio

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

**Chromium**

**Version 120.0.6099.129 (Official Build) for Linux Mint (64-bit)**

Audio stopped working in my copy of Chromium.

I can still watch and hear videos with other applications, including YouTube videos with other browsers, but not Chromium.

Any ideas for things I can check?

Comment: Did you try this : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=213693

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using synaptic to do a complete removal of Chromium and then installing it again.